# How do I print this PDF with the A1 dimensions?

Tags: pdf, resize, scale, digital-printing

https://jordanm.co.uk/downloads/LifeCalendar.pdf

I have to print the above PDF for an assignment. When I download the PDF and look at the properties, ***420 × 594 mm (portrait)*** is stated. **I want an **A1 (594mm x 841 mm)** version of this PDF.**

[image]

However, when I select print on Google Chrome, the only largest option I am given is A3. [image]

**How do I make an A1 version of this PDF?**

The printer, which can print A1, is at my school so I have not connected my laptop to a printer. This is why the Print Destination is "Microsoft Print to PDF". I'm also a complete beginner in printing.

I genuinely apologise if this is the wrong place to submit this question!

Comment: Hi. The available sheet sizes are dependent on the printer driver.  The Microsoft Print to PDF driver doesn't support A1, as far as I know.  Instead, you should probably print this directly to a printer which actually supports A1.  If you are taking this to a print shop, just them to print it at A1.  You don't need to do anything. They will know how to scale it up.

Answer (score 0):

I *really* don't understand why the Print Dialog **destination** is set to print to a PDF. That file **is** a PDF. Just save/download the file and you'll have a PDF. You do not need to "print to PDF".

However, in the **Print Dialog**...

`Scale > Fit to Paper`

or

`Scale > Fit to Printable Area`

PDFs are *not designed* to just arbitrarily be resized. They can be scaled, but generally not resized easily. PDF is a self-contained, end-use format, it's not a "construction" format. If you want the file at different dimensions, and looking as if it were designed to fit those dimensions, one would generally need to *rebuild* the layout to fit new dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How does guarantee that the file will be printed with the dimensions (594mm x 841 mm)?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. You are printing a PDF *to a PDF* which makes no sense. Are you trying to resize the PDF but keep it a PDF? A1 is 594 x 841mm - that PDF is roughly  419x954mm It *doesn't fit* on an A1 sheet, it's too long. So, scale it to fit. Is your printer capable of printing A1?? Set the proper print destination and scale it to fit. It will scale **proportionally** - meaning it will be narrower than the A1 width.

Comment: That PDF is **not** 420x594mm - its, roughy 419x954mm (16.53x23.39 inches) You're looking at it **reduced** to 95%. That *may* account for why you think the dimensions are smaller than they are. Or... the "properties" are merely showing what's *currently displayed*, not the actual file dimensions.

Comment: I have just confirmed on Google that 23.39 inches is 594mm.

Comment: Apologies @useresu apparently I transposed the 5 and 9..... my bad. .. oops. :) I'm not known for dyslexia.. but it seems to have taken a role here.

Comment: It happens, no worries. :)

Comment: The sizes in the Print dialog are in direct correlation to the Print Destination Driver. If the driver doesn't support a size, then that size is not an option. You need to first use the *correct* print destination driver -- you may then actually see A1 as an option if your printer supports A1.

Comment: The printer at my school prints A1 pieces of paper. So all I have to do is (1) Connect my laptop to it. (2) Select the printer in the Print Destination. (3) Select A1. (4) Press print. Is that correct? I don't have to do anything to do the PDF file itself?

Comment: The PDF fits on an A1 naturally, so if you can select A1 in the Page Size for printing you should be good to go. I think the trouble you are seeing is all due to not having the correct Print Destination Driver selected.